# PE SizeOfImage wrong

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to get current size from PE but seem wrong

i have this code:

```
hModule = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
pDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
pNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)hModule+pDH->e_lfanew);
dwSize = pNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
```

here is the difference:
current exec => 246 kb
pNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage=>356352=> 348kb

So, what is wrong with this code, why PE is different in Kb.

Comment: `246 kb` this is what size ? from where ?

Comment: The exec is 246 kb on disk... but the function of pNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage result on 356352 or 348 kb.?..why?

Comment: because `SizeOfImage` is size of image in memory. it must not equal to size of disk. usual it different

Comment: Is your code C or C++?

Answer (score 5):

The size of a loaded image is not necessarily (actually, almost certainly never) the same as the size of the binary on disk. For example, when you write a program that contains some static data, the compiler has to allocate space for that data in the image. However, if that data is, e.g., uninitialized or all zero, it would be wasteful to just store loads of zeros in the binary. No one is going to be happy that they have to download a 1+ GiB exe file full of zeros just because you wrote

```
int a[1024*1024*256] = {};
```

somewhere in your code. Instead, the .exe file will simply store the size and location at which that data is supposed to be in the loaded image and the OS will allocate and map appropriate memory at that location when the image is loaded…